# How to return and parse multiple properties of an object?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that fetches reports from a URI and displays the datasource(s) username. However, we'd like to get the name of the reports so we know what datasource username is associated with what report for tracking purposes.

`listReports()` function parses each report and returns its ID `return $_.Id`

The report ID is a hash like

> 12b1657c-dc07-5b35-afc0-b0d6c9047860

The `$_` object also has other meaningful properties, such as `$_.Name`, and `$_.Path`

**Current output** of full script (from the last foreach loop that is) is a list of Datasource usernames (not the report IDs):

```
TKCSIMPORT
payroll
si_51932_p_00h
payroll

payroll
tkcsimport
```

which is what we want, but i also want to display the report name/paths associated with each of those usernames, e.g. **expected output:**

```
DS Username      Report Name
TKCSIMPORT       Report1
payroll          Report2
si_51932_p_00h   Report3
payroll          Report3

payroll          Report4
tkcsimport       Report5
```

How do I do this?

I would try `return $_.Id, $_.Name, $_.Path` in `listReports()` but then the challenge is how to map the extra properties here `@(listReports("http://pbi.domain.gm.com/reports"))`

Full script:

```
# lists all the reports on the server that are available to your user account
Function listReports($baseURL) {
    $reports = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri "$baseURL/api/v2.0/CatalogItems"
    $reports.value | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "PowerBIReport"} | foreach { 
            #Write-Host ("{0} {1} {2}" -f $_.Id, $_.Name, $_.Path)
            return $_.Id
    }
}

Function getDataSources($baseURL, $reportID) {
    $sources = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri "$baseURL/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports($reportID)/DataSources"
    if ($sources.value -is [array]) {
        return $sources.value
    } else {
        return @($sources.value)
    }
}

$reportIDs = @(listReports("http://pbi.domain.com/reports"))

foreach($reportID in $reportIDs) {
    (getDataSources "http://pbi.domain.com/reports" $reportID | % {
        return $_.DataModelDataSource.Username
    })
}
```

Comment: you lost me at `@(listReports("http://pbi.domain.gm.com/reports"))`. What are you trying to do with this? So you want:`_.Id, $_.Name, $_.Path` from your `listReports($baseURL)` function, and then what else?

Comment: Why not just `return $_` from `listReports`? Then you'll have access to all the properties

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I am using this `@(listReports("http://pbi.domain.gm.com/reports"))` to store the returned result of `listReports()`, which currently is just storing the reports' IDs. But i suppose returning `$_` is a better approach than returning `_.Id, $_.Name, $_.Path` in the `listReports()` per Mathias suggestion. So if i do that, now that all properties are stored in the array `@(listReports("http://pbi.domain.gm.com/reports"))`, how do i loop through each of the 3 properties (`.Id, .Name, .Path`) here `foreach($reportID in $reportIDs)`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good suggestion! So if i do that, now that all properties are stored in the array `@(listReports("http://pbi.domain.gm.com/reports"))`, how do i loop through each of the 3 properties (`.Id, .Name, .Path`) here `foreach($reportID in $reportIDs)`?

Comment: `listReports "http://pbi.domain.gm.com/reports" |Select Id,Name,Path`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks i figured it out using pscustomobject, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Warning. This is an illustrative example**. It isn't solution for your specific code

`[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()` returns a **HashTable**, `.GetEnumerator()` return an IEnumerator that iterates through a collection. Each element of Enumerator have two properties **Key** and **Value**. In this example I select **Key**, **Value** and the third property is calculated an named as **Size**.

The statement `@{ Name="Size"; Expression = {$_.Value.Length}}` is the third custom selected property.

`Name="Size"` is the name of the calculated property

`Expression = {$_.Value.Length}` is the value of the calculated property. In this case is the Length of the Value property.

`{$_.Value.Length}` is an script block that returns a value.

`$_` is the value of the current object on the pipe.

**The Code**

```
# //Selecting all objects
$enumerator = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables().GetEnumerator() | `
Select-Object -Property Key, Value, @{ Name="Size"; Expression = {$_.Value.ToString().ToUpper() }}

# //Alternative solution with PS Custom Objects. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8397835/cataster
$enumerator2 = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables().GetEnumerator() |  Foreach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $_.Key
        Value = $_.Value
        Size = $_.Value.Length
    }
} 

# //Printing all selected objects
$enumerator | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "{ Key= $($_.Key), Value= $($_.Value), Size= $($_.Size) }"
}

# //Print all selected objects as list, all properties
$enumerator | Format-List

# //Print all selected objects as table, specific properties
$enumerator | Format-Table -Property Key, Size
```

**Output** Illustrative example

```
{ Key= TEMP, Value= C:\Users\Megam\AppData\Local\Temp, Size= 33 }
{ Key= PSModulePath, Value= C:\Users\Megam\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;c:\Users\Megam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2021.12.0\modules, Size= 284 }
{ Key= HOMEDRIVE, Value= C:, Size= 2 }
{ Key= APPDATA, Value= C:\Users\Megam\AppData\Roaming, Size= 30 }
{ Key= LANG, Value= en_US.UTF-8, Size= 11 }
{ Key= PATHEXT, Value= .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL, Size= 58 }
{ Key= CommonProgramFiles(x86), Value= C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, Size= 35 }
{ Key= ProgramData, Value= C:\ProgramData, Size= 14 }
{ Key= PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, Value= AMD64, Size= 5 }
{ Key= VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS, Value= --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node, Size= 32 }
{ Key= TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION, Value= 1.63.2, Size= 6 }
{ Key= ProgramFiles(x86), Value= C:\Program Files (x86), Size= 22 }
{ Key= SystemDrive, Value= C:, Size= 2 }
{ Key= USERDOMAIN, Value= DESKTOP-9EPNRSP, Size= 15 }
{ Key= COLORTERM, Value= truecolor, Size= 9 }
{ Key= ProgramW6432, Value= C:\Program Files, Size= 16 }
{ Key= HOMEPATH, Value= \Users\Megam, Size= 12 }
{ Key= TERM_PROGRAM, Value= vscode, Size= 6 }
{ Key= CommonProgramW6432, Value= C:\Program Files\Common Files, Size= 29 }
{ Key= windir, Value= C:\Windows, Size= 10 }
```

*as List*

```
Key   : CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME
Value : \\.\pipe\crashpad_9536_MITAYLIDBVJOLRAM
Size  : 39

Key   : PUBLIC
Value : C:\Users\Public
Size  : 15

Key   : COLORTERM
Value : truecolor
Size  : 9

Key   : APPDATA
Value : C:\Users\Megam\AppData\Roaming
Size  : 30

Key   : ComSpec
Value : C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Size  : 27

Key   : NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
Value : 8
Size  : 1

Key   : PSModulePath
Value : C:\Users\Megam\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules;C:\Program Files\Windows
        PowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;c:\Users\Megam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2021.12.0\modules
Size  : 284

Key   : COMPUTERNAME
Value : DESKTOP-9EPNRSP
Size  : 15

Key   : ProgramFiles(x86)
Value : C:\Program Files (x86)
Size  : 22

Key   : SESSIONNAME
Value : Console
Size  : 7
```

asTable

```
Key                             Size
---                             ----
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                    1
ALLUSERSPROFILE                   14
HOMEDRIVE                          2
InsaneAppName                     59
PSExecutionPolicyPreference       12
GIT_ASKPASS                      100
AppName                           49
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE           64
TMP                               33
PROCESSOR_REVISION                 4
OneDriveConsumer                  23
XXX__YYY                          32
SystemRoot                        10
VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE             35
SystemDrive                        2
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE             5
IntelliJ IDEA                     54
CommonProgramW6432                29
ProgramFiles                      16
windir                            10
HOMEPATH                          12
USERNAME                           5
TERM_PROGRAM                       6
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE         15
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS     32
POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL    4
LOGONSERVER                       17
USERPROFILE                       14
Path                             635
TEMP                              33
USERDOMAIN                        15
CommonProgramFiles                29
PATHEXT                           58
CommonProgramFiles(x86)           35
ProgramData                       14
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP       9
OS                                10
OneDrive                          23
LANG                              11
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION               6
ProgramW6432                      16
DriverData                        38
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN          105
LOCALAPPDATA                      28
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER              50
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME         39
PUBLIC                            15
COLORTERM                          9
APPDATA                           30
ComSpec                           27
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS               1
PSModulePath                     284
COMPUTERNAME                      15
ProgramFiles(x86)                 22
SESSIONNAME                        7
```

**References**
[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2)
[Custom expressions in common pipeline commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2#custom-expressions-in-common-pipeline-commands)
[Example 11: Create calculated properties for each InputObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject)
[Format-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-7.2)
[Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2)

**██████ UPDATE for your CODE**
You can use this

```
# //Select Id, Name, Path, UpperName(custom), PathSize(custom) properties. 
$reports.value | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "PowerBIReport"} | Select-Object -Property Id, Name, Path, @{ Name="UpperName"; Expression={$_.Name.ToString().ToUpper()}}, @{ Name="PathSize"; Expression={$_.Path.Length}}
```

Comment: Thanks Joma, i figured it out using pscustomobject, see my answer :)

Comment: You can print formatted list with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2  or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-7.2 e.g.  ```$listObject | Format-List``` . Check update.

Comment: Your solution is nice. I learned something new with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a neat way to accomplish what i want using pscustomobjects!

```
$webPortalURL = "https://pbi.domain.com/reports"

Function listReports($baseURL) {
    $reports = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri "$baseURL/api/v2.0/CatalogItems"
    $reports.value | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "PowerBIReport"} | foreach { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Id = $_.Id
            Name = $_.Name
            Path = $_.Path
        }
    }
}

Function getDataSources($baseURL, $reportID) {
    $sources = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri "$baseURL/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports($reportID)/DataSources"
    if ($sources.value -is [array]) {
        return $sources.value
    } else {
        return @($sources.value)
    }
}

$reportList = @(listReports($webPortalURL))

$ReportsDatasourceUsernames_pscoArray = @()
$loopCount = 1

foreach($report in $reportList) {
    (getDataSources $webPortalURL $report.Id | % {
        #return $_.DataModelDataSource.Username
        $ReportsDatasourceUsernames_pscoArray += [PSCustomObject]@{
            '#' = $loopCount
            'Datasource Username' = $_.DataModelDataSource.Username
            'Report Name' = $report.Name
            'Report Path' = <#"=HYPERLINK(""$($webPortalURL + `"/powerbi`" + $($report.Path))"",""$($report.Name)"")"#> "<a href='$($webPortalURL + `"/powerbi`" + $($report.Path))'>$($report.Name)</a>"
            #'Status' = "$($error[0])`r`n$($error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)`r`n$($error[0].ScriptStackTrace)"
        }
    })
    $loopCount++
}

$ReportsDatasourceUsernames_pscoArray
```